# Getting warning in download.php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am running this file:

```
 $file_name = "WEL_log_".date('Y_m');

 $url  = 'http://www.welserver.com/WEL0521/'.$file_name.'.xls';

 $base_path = '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/';

 $tmp_path =  $base_path.'tmp_'.$file_name.'.tsv';
 $path = $base_path.$file_name.'.tsv';
 $current_month_path = $base_path.'current_month.tsv';
 $latest_path = $base_path.'latest.tsv';


function downloadFile ($url, $path) {

 global $latest_path;
 global $tmp_path;
 global $current_month_path;
global $base_path;

 $newfname = $tmp_path;
 $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
 if ($file) {
```

The line below is line 37 in coding:

```
 $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

 if ($newf){
    while(!feof($file)) {
      fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
    }
}
}

 if ($file) {
 fclose($file);
 }

if ($newf) {
copy($tmp_path, $current_month_path);

rename($tmp_path, $path);


fclose($newf);

write_latest_data($path, $latest_path);
 }

  }

  function write_latest_data($read_file_path, $write_file_path, $no_of_new_lines=10){

$file = file($read_file_path);

$write_f = fopen ($write_file_path, "wb");

$line_count = count($file) > $no_of_new_lines ? $no_of_new_lines : count($file);

if ($write_f){

    fwrite($write_f, $file[0], 1024 * 8 );

    $file = array_reverse($file);

    for($i=0; $i < $line_count; $i++){
        fwrite($write_f, $file[$i], 1024 * 8 );
    }

    fclose($write_f);
}
```

and getting this warning

> Warning: fopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/tmp_WEL_log_2013_08.tsv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/download.php on line 37

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is pretty clear that you have a permissions error, which doesn't have anything to do with your code.

Comment: Might try running `chown apache /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/ -R && chmod 775 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/ -R`

Comment: @Brad Thanks for your response I got it fixed..

Comment: @Connor Peet Thanks for your response I got it fixed..

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that the file cannot be opend for writing. Check if you have write permission in your base path:
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/website/

You should check with which user and usergroup the apache is running. In most cases it is www-data for both. So you files in the webfoot should have the user and group www-data assigned. If both, user and group, match the permission 755 should be enough for your base path. If only the group matches 775 should be ok. If nothing matches you have to set 777 but this shouldn't be done on a live system.

Comment: Thanks for the response I get it fixed ... Now the thing is I use this file to download latest data to plot charts, but now they are not getting updated... I am using cronnix to keep them updated.